# Git Hub - restart a repositiory from scratch

Tags: github

I created a repository (initial commit) and put the wrong URL as remote origin, how do I restart / remove the files, commit and remote from github so I can start over completely?

I have a backup of all the files.

Comment: You don't need to.  Just remove the remote, add the correct one, then push again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the GitHub [documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-a-repository):

1. Navigate to the repository you want to delete.
2. Settings buttonIn the repository action bar, click **Settings**.
3. Repository deletion buttonUnder Danger Zone, click **Delete this repository**.
4. **Read the warnings**
5. To verify that you're deleting the the correct repository, type the name of the repository you want to delete.
6. Click **I understand the consequences, delete this repository**.